# GUID Inserting as Username while create DNN user programmatically

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I have write code for create DNN user programmatically by following code but it is inserting Username like this `50c5c87e-bba7-4fc8-b2b4-1d9e3e388dc5-contracthiring@outlook.com`. It is something looks like merging GUID + EmailAddress. But it should be `li_ + FirstName + LastName` as I creating dynamically by following code.

I written Username log after & before  below line. It seems very strange thing. Below is my output.

```
'Response.Write("objUserInfo Before: " & objUserInfo.Username)
objUserCreateStatus = objMembershipProvider.CreateUser(objUserInfo)
'Response.Write("objUserInfo: " & objUserInfo.Username)
```

Output of Username:

> Before: li_Andrea Simon
>
> After: 50c5c87e-bba7-4fc8-b2b4-1d9e3e388dc5-contracthiring@outlook.com

My Code:

```
Try
                    If MySettings("LinkedinUserNamePrefix") <> "" Then
                        fsUsername = MySettings("LinkedinUserNamePrefix") & objPerson.Firstname & " " & objPerson.Lastname
                    Else
                        fsUsername = objPerson.Firstname & " " & objPerson.Lastname
                    End If
                Catch
                End Try

         'Register user to the site
        Dim objUserInfo As New DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo
        objUserInfo.PortalID = Me.PortalId
        objUserInfo.Username = fsUsername
        objUserInfo.FirstName = fName
        objUserInfo.LastName = lName
        objUserInfo.Email = EmailAdd
        objUserInfo.DisplayName = fsUsername
        objUserInfo.Membership.Username = fsUsername
        objUserInfo.Membership.Email = EmailAdd
        objUserInfo.Membership.Password = fsUsername

        ' User Profile
        objUserInfo.Profile.PreferredLocale = PortalSettings.DefaultLanguage
        objUserInfo.Profile.FirstName = fName
        objUserInfo.Profile.LastName = lName

        'Set Membership
        objUserInfo.Membership.Approved = True

        'Bind membership to user
        objUserInfo.IsSuperUser = False

        Dim objUserCreateStatus As UserCreateStatus = UserCreateStatus.AddUser
        Dim objMembershipProvider As DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.MembershipProvider = DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.MembershipProvider.Instance()
        'Response.Write("objUserInfo Before: " & objUserInfo.Username)
        objUserCreateStatus = objMembershipProvider.CreateUser(objUserInfo)
        'Response.Write("objUserInfo: " & objUserInfo.Username)
```

What is the problem in CreateUser method. Is it problem in DNN library.

I'm using DNN 07.04.00.

Comment: Are you by chance running into a username that is already taken and the system is generating something for you?

Comment: I tried a lot of different user details but for every user, above code inserted Username like `GUID + Email`.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I have the exact same problem right now...

Comment: Yes. That was an issue in DNN framework. Use newer version of DNN and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncheck "Use Email Address as Username" under Admin settings, if checked.

Comment: I have already tried it with checked/un-checked but still insert username like `0b279945-8d3b-48cf-ba90-4084fb2174bc-contrac@outlook.com`

Comment: Try Signup using default DNN Register module and see if the username still in same format, if not then the issue is in your code.